# How do I refresh an incremental data sync i.e. run a snapshot build?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I want to be able to reset a JDBC data sync from source if something goes wrong.
Ideally, replacing the last N days of data.

I'd prefer not to have multi-step process involving editing the SQL query itself.
I tried disabling incremental mode, but this doesn't clear out the old data.
In code repositories, I can increase the `semantic_version` number to cause data to refresh.
Another angle to take could be to rollback to a previous version of the dataset, and then rerun the sync - but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the Foundry GUI.

How can this be done for an incremental data sync?

Answer (score 1):

Doing an ad-hoc snapshot build with an incremental data-sync is currently an 8 step process.

Make these changes to the data sync:

- Change the transaction type to Snapshot (from Append)
- Edit the query to remove references to the incremental parameter, and ensure the result set will be empty i.e. add `WHERE 1=0`.
- Disable incremental mode

Then save and build to clear out the dataset.

Reverse the changes to get back to incremental mode, then save and build.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to turn off incremental mode on the Sync, run a snapshot build, and then turn incremental mode back on for the subsequent builds.

Sticking to what is available in the UI, indeed you can't "rollback" to a specific version of the dataset.

Comment: Thanks will try this but I believe the query needs to be edited, since it depends on the incremental parameter which will break when incremental is disabled.

Comment: disabling incremental mode is not enough (whether you mean disabling incremental mode, or changing the transaction type to snapshot)